# Remove multi line pattern with special characters from file

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need to remove multi line pattern from a file.
For example:

```
  <Command name="somecom" type="type" >
     <input name="some input" />
     <output name="some output" />
  </Command>
  <?ignore <Command name="somecom" type="type" >
     <input name="some input" />
     <output name="some output" />
  </Command> ?>
```

Section to remove starts with:

```
 <?ignore
```

Ends with:

```
 ?>
```

I want to use regex to do this. python3.6.3

```
with open('graph.xml', 'r') as readXML:
    tempFile = readXML.read()
    patr = re.compile("<?ignore.*?>", re.MULTILINE)
    tempFile = re.sub(patr,"",tempFile)
    print(tempFile)
```

Result:

```
  <Command name="somecom" type="type" >
     <input name="some input" />
     <output name="some output" />
  </Command>
  <?
     <input name="some input" />
     <output name="some output" />
  </Command> ?>
```

I would like all section to be deleted, not just partial first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove multi line patterns using this pattern `<\?ignore.+?\?>`:

Example:

```
import re

str = """
  <Command name="somecom" type="type" >
     <input name="some input" />
     <output name="some output" />
  </Command>
  <?ignore <Command name="somecom" type="type" >
     <input name="some input" />
     <output name="some output" />
  </Command> ?> 
  """

print(re.sub(r'<\?ignore.+?\?>', '', str, flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL))
```

This prints out:

```
  <Command name="somecom" type="type" >
     <input name="some input" />
     <output name="some output" />
  </Command>
```

Do not forget to use the flags otherwise the replacement will not work:

```
flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either make the dot match a newline using for example a modifier `(?s)`  and escape the question mark `\?` to match it literally. You might als make the dot start approach non greedy `.*?`

```
(?s)<\?ignore.*?\?>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VbA6r7/2) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/KYDCdG)

Or you can use a repeating pattern to match a line that does not contain `?>` using a negative lookahead:

```
<\?ignore\b.*\n(?!.*\?>)(?:.*\n)*.*\?>
```

- `<\?ignore\b.*\n` Match `<?ignore` followed 1+ times any char followed by a newline
- `(?!.*\?>)` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not `?>`
- `(?:.*\n)*` Repeat 0+ times matching any char except a newline followed by a newline
- `.*\?>` Match 0+ times any char and `?>`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VbA6r7/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/t6tTgz)

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed answer!
I used flags version since it's more friendly than (?s) modifier

Answer (score 0):

`?` is an optional quantifier in regex, so that `a?` means the char `a` is optional. To detect litterally this char, you need to escape it.

try with

```
<\?ignore.*\?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because ? affects "greedy" quantifiers:  * and + in a way that makes them "lazy" -- * and + begin to search for first occurence of character/group after them and, then match, return. So, to make your regex work, you just need to escape ? symbol with \

`<?ignore.*\?>` would work as you expect.